# Is it better to serve media(images/video) by creating separate http server listening to it in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am serving media/videos from nodejs application apart from normal REST API calls. I have read somewhere that it is not ideal to serve this, since it may consume CPU in main thread. If we consider this, is it better to create separate http server in same code to serve request to media, so that it does not affect normal REST API calls. Or we can create node cluster to achieve the same ?

Comment: It's better to have separate media server

Comment: @El. By separate media server you mean through node js only...right ?? or any media server software?

Comment: By separate media server I mean any server that is able to send stream of binary data over http